# How to make a player fly to a point in lua roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want my player to fly at a certain speed to the specified point after running the code, it should not be teleportation, but exactly smooth movement, as in this video - https://youtu.be/_p7HmviCIF8?t=231

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service, you should make an attempt to solve your problem. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, do not cheat in games. It's unfair for other players and ruins the experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case here, if you want an exact time for every teleport, you're gonna need to use `TweenService`.

So you're first going to reference where you're going. Let's say that our point is a `CFrame` value of an object.
Remember, whenever we want to tp our character, we use `CFrame`s and not `Position`s.

So first, you're gonna wanna make a `TweenInfo`, which is basically the parameters of the tween, e.g Time to get to the point, the movement it should have (Linear, Elastic, etc.), etc.

And then you're gonna need a table containing of the property that needs to be changed. In which case we want the CFrame value of the `HumanoidRootPart` to be the point we set.

Then we're going to make a new tween and have it tween our `HumanoidRootPart` CFrame to the point CFrame.

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local TweeningInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    -- The time to get there here
)
local TargetValue = {
    CFrame = -- Point CFrame here.
}

local Tween = TweenService:Create(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart, TweeningInfo, TargetValue)

Tween:Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

For your video its just an script for a exploit like synapse x but there are a lot of pastebin or free scripts in toolbox or simply video on that or use the adonis admin on studio and run this in chat :fly me "speed"